# module 'mediapipe' has no attribute 'solutions'

Tags: mediapipe

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/qiancong/PycharmProjects/posetest/TestProject.py", line 7, in 
detector = pm.poseDetector()
File "/Users/qiancong/PycharmProjects/posetest/PoseModule.py", line 18, in **init**
self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
AttributeError: module 'mediapipe' has no attribute 'solutions'

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you have a folder named mediapipe in the execution directory and is trying to access that folder instead of the actual library.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no similar file name, but there are still errors like this

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a mac silicon (M1 or M2), maybe you was install both of `mediapipe` and `mediapipe-silicon`. So just run:

```
pip3 uninstall mediapipe-silicon
pip3 uninstall mediapipe
pip3 install mediapipe
```